# Can $(1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{2^2})(1-\frac{1}{2^3})...(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})(\frac{1}{2^n})$ be simplified?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Can $(1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{2^2})(1-\frac{1}{2^3})...(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})(\frac{1}{2^n})$ be simplified? It seems like an expression from a simple induction proof problem that's missing its result.

Comment: It would also be interesting to determine (if possible) the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @LordSoth, the infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-2^{-k})$ converges, so dividing the partial products by $2^n$ yields a limit of $0$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Oh yes, what I had in mind was without the $\frac{1}{2^n}$ factor. There was even supposed to be a name (if my memory is not tricking me) for that constant now that you have written it in $\prod$-form.

Comment: @LordSoth, it can be written $(1/2)_\infty$ (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html)) though I'd be interested to see if there is a more elementary form.

Comment: @lordSoth That is a better question as n tends to infinity. We can show that the expression is between 0 and 1 as n tends to infinity.

Comment: @LordSoth but I haven't been able to find a limit

Comment: Ok we have established the limit to be 0. Can anyone find a closed form of the expression?

Comment: $$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-q^k) = \phi(q) = e^{-\frac{\pi i\tau}{12}} \eta(\tau)$$ where $q = e^{2\pi i\tau}$. $\phi(q)$ is the [Euler functon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) and $\eta(\tau)$ is the [Dedekind eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function).

Answer (score 1):

You could write

$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{7}{8} \cdot \frac{15}{16} \cdot \dots \cdot \frac{2^{n - 1} - 1}{2^{n - 1}} \cdot \frac{1}{2^n}$$

and then the denominator is

$$2 \cdot 4 \cdot \dots 2^n = 2^{1 + 2 + 3 + \dots + n} = 2^{n(n + 1)/2}$$

while the numerator is

$$(2 - 1) (2^2 - 1) (2^3 - 1) \cdots (2^{n - 1} - 1) = \prod_{k = 1}^n (2^k - 1) = (-1)^n (2; 2)_n$$

where $(2; 2)_n$ is a [$q$-Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html). So the final "simplification" would be

$$\frac{(-1)^n (2; 2)_n}{2^{n(n + 1)/2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Still no closed form, just another reformulation.
If I use the logarithm of your product $p_n$ (omitting the trailing $1/2^n$-factor), express the logarithms by their Mercator series, and change order of evaluation of the double sums then I get the following sum 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty } \log(p_n) = - \sum_{k=1}^n {1 \over 2^k-1 }\frac 1k $$

I think I've read in some article of Euler, that for the sum (without the 1/k-cofactor) "we cannot find a simplification"

Answer (score 0):

It can be transformed into
$$
\frac{(2-1)(2^2-1)(2^3-1)\cdots(2^{n-1}-1)}{2^{1+2+3+\cdots +n}}=
\frac{(2-1)(2^2-1)(2^3-1)\cdots(2^{n-1}-1)}{2^{n(n+1)/2}}
$$
but whether this is a simplification I don't know.

Comment: The numerator doesn't seem to have a nicer expression: http://oeis.org/A005329.

Comment: Yes, so far this is as good as I have found too. I guess I am trying to get rid of the infinite product as eventually I would like to find the value when n tends to infinity.Can anyone do anything to the numerator?

Comment: @GusMarks, http://oeis.org/A005329 says that this sequence has a limit $\approx 0.2887880950866024212788997219294585937270\cdots$ but implies it is not one with a closed form.

Comment: by then we multiply by $\frac{1}{2^n}$. So the limit is 0.

Comment: @GusMarks, I meant your original sequence of fractions.

Comment: ok thanks, I understand anyway. And I am saddened that there is apparently no closed form.